# Magento - Extension is slowing down to a crawl

Tags: php, sql, magento, magento-1.9

I'm working on adding an additional column to an existing backend extension.

I'm determining the sells of the products to display their health of (roughly) the last 3 months.

If I implement this column the page takes upwards of a minute to be generated.

The code for the query I'm adding to the extension is:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-90 days'));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-0 days'));

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('order_items' => 'sales_flat_order_item'), 
    "`order_items`.`product_id` = `e`.`entity_id` AND 
    `order_items`.`created_at` BETWEEN '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'  
    AND `order_items`.`order_id` IN (SELECT entity_id FROM sales_flat_order 
            WHERE status = 'processing' OR  status = 'complete' OR status = 'closed')
    ",
    array('order_id', 'product_id')
);
$collection->getSelect()->columns('COUNT(order_items.order_id) AS stock_health');
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

The code for the column I'm adding is:

```
$stockManagerModel = Mage::getModel('stocklist/status');
$this->addColumn('stock_health', array(
    'header' => 'Health', //Mage::helper('stocklist')->__('Health'),
    'align' => 'right',
    'filter' => false,
    'width' => '60px',
    'order_callback' => array($this, '_customSort'),
    'renderer' => 'stocklist/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_health',
    'index' => 'stock_health',
));
```

What is causing this extension to be so slow after this addition? What changes could/should be made? Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure what parts of this is original and whats yours, but instead of the subselect can you do an inner join of sales_flat_order where status = 'processing' OR  status = 'complete' OR status = 'closed'

Comment: If you enable the Varien profiler and developer mode, you'll get a breakdown of the process timing at the bottom of your screen - might be useful for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit doubt, are you checking your compilation process? Is it disabled or do you Run Compilation process once the module is enabled?

Comment: Compilation is disabled. Enabling it appears to have no effect on the time it takes to generate the page.